# JavaScript window.open _self issues

Tags: javascript, self, window.open

I have some old code that I want to open into the same window

```
if(sgame=='BIN') {
  window.open('http://<%=Application("domain")%>/client/client.asp?z=<%=encode(session("username")&"|"&session("password")&"|"&session("id"))%>&lang=<%=session("lang")%>&host='+shost+'&port='+sport+'&dat='+sfolder
             ,'bingogame'+Math.round(Math.random()*9999)
             ,'_self'
             ,'resizable=no
             ,scrollbars=no
             ,width=1024
             ,height=768');
```

From what I understand I put '_self', in the right place, but it is still opening a new browser window.

Answer (score 0):

`+sfolder,'bingogame'+Math.round(Math.random()*9999)`

The above code piece has an extra `comma` between `sfolder` and `bingogame`. Your second parameter should have been `'_self'`, but instead, because of that extra `comma`, `'_self'` has become the third parameter. Fix that, and it should work.

[`Window.open`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) will give you more info about the parameters.